# Jenkins build not getting triggered on scheduled time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to schedule a build every day at a particular time say 4pm.
And hence I have set up the build periodically to :

```
H 16 * * *
```

I am noticing that the build either doesn't get triggered at the scheduled time or else gets triggered at a random time , ( 4 hours prior to scheduled build)

I want to understand how scheduling works for the build to understand why is it not triggering build at the intended time.
I suspected that master node would be in a timezone other than what I want but that is also not the case.

Inspite of setting timezone as below:

```
TZ=America/Los_Angeles
H 16 * * *
```